# Android running Phonegap app - Blurred/resized screen

Tags: android, html, cordova

I'm building a Phonegap app and testing it on a Samsung Galaxy 5 smartphone and a Samsung Galaxy Tab tablet.

It seems to be fine on my computer screen, but in the mobiles', the elements are rendered in variable scale sizes (probably to fit in).
On the smartphone the whole screen becomes shrinked, and on the tablet the screen is stretched. (this include margins/widths/heights/images/canvas). This makes all pixel-detailed art become blurred/anti-aliased.

I'm kind of a pixel perfectionist and I need my app to render with a fixed pixel aspect and size. Is that possible?

Thank you!

-edit-
It turns out that I had this meta tag on my header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

which was causing the stretching on the tablet. The smartphone is still shrinking it all...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is a known bug in Android 2.1, at least the Canvas part (as far as I have searched) which was the most important for me.